# I'm trying to understad better how objects work in Python

Tags: python, object, optparse, python-object

In this definition, i'm using optparse to accept some argumets on the command line. So, my question is how the method add_option creates an atribute with the name from *dest*, that can be called from an object.

```
def main():
     parser = optparse.OptionParser('usage%prog ' + \
                    '-H <target host> -u <user> -F <password list>')
     parser.add_option('-H' , dest='tgtHost', type='string', \
                     help='specify target host')
     parser.add_option('-u' , dest='user', type='string', \
                     help='specify the user')
     parser.add_option('-F', dest='passwdFile', type='string', help='specify password file')
     (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
     host = options.tgtHost
     passwdFile = options.passwdFile
     user = options.user
```

Comment: It looks like something happened to the code formatting that introduced a bunch of `**`s.

Comment: If you want to know *how* it works, you can browse the source for `add_option(...)` - https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/optparse.py#l1008

Comment: Thanks man! Thats a very good start.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is provided here :
[optparse — Parser for command line options](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html)